# Update employee pay by 2 dollars if worked for more than a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update employee pay but I only want to increase pay if they have worked for more than a year with company.  I'm not sure how to tell the query the one year part.  I'm adding to all employees pay and not only the ones that have worked with company for over a year. How do I tell SQL that I only want employees that have worked for more than 365 days?

```
UPDATE
    TEmployees
SET
    monHourlyRate =  monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dteHireDate > 365
```

Comment: Is `dteHireDate` a date or datetime column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    TEmployees
SET
    monHourlyRate =  monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dteHireDate <= DATEADD(year,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

You will probably see a common answer like the following this which works but could be off if a leap year because a leap year would have been 366 days.

```
UPDATE
    TEmployees
SET
    monHourlyRate =  monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY,dteHireDate,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) + 1 >= 365
```

Comment: The specific stated requirement in the question is to use > 365 days.

Comment: @MartinSmith actually it is > 365 in the question and 1 year in the title so I am showing one and you are showing the other.  it is probable that leap years aren't being considered as I see in plenty of posts.  It is a bit of a pet peeve for me not to consider it so I like to show how to handle it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
UPDATE
    TEmployees
SET
    monHourlyRate =  monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dteHireDate < DATEADD(DAY, -365, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
    TEmployees
SET
    monHourlyRate =  monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dteHireDate < DATEADD(YY,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
    TEmployees
SET
    monHourlyRate =  monHourlyRate + 2
WHERE
    dteHireDate <= DATEADD(year,-1, (GETDATE())
```